# App Store application submitting error because of xcoredatamodel

Tags: swift, xcdatamodel

After I submitted my application, apple sent an email that is below. I could not where the problem is ? Can anyone help me in this issue ?

```
enter code here

* This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for 
 /****.app/CoreData.framework is missing or could not be read.
* Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '****.app/CoreData.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.
* Invalid Bundle Structure - The framework at '****.app/CoreData.framework' is not permitted. Do not include platform frameworks in your app.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you check `Core Data` when you create the project ?

[image]

---

### Add Core Data to an existing project

**First,** add this code in the `AppDelagate.swift`

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
    The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "whateverYouLikeHere")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support
func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

If you run just with that, you should get this error:
[image]

To resolve that, you should import `CoreData`

[image]

Next, we’ll need to change the container name to match our main project.

[image]

Next, we have to create the actual data file. So, let’s create a new file, `⌘N`, scroll down to the `Core Data` section and select `Data Model`, then continue through and name the file after your project.

[image]

---

> If want to know more, you should read this: [add score Data to an existing project](https://medium.com/@shawnbierman/how-to-add-core-data-to-an-existing-xcode-8-and-swift-3-project-508781b3e1c4)

[Sources](https://medium.com/@shawnbierman/how-to-add-core-data-to-an-existing-xcode-8-and-swift-3-project-508781b3e1c4)

Comment: Yes, it is inside the project